# Vim - How to search and reaplace based on search

Tags: search, vim, macros, replace, let

What i would like to do :

Every time i find something based on `s[w|l].*[0-9]\.\*` replace the end of that string\search .* with `%s/\.\*/\\\\\.\.\*/g`

Already tried with standard search and replace, but couldn't do it.

Thanks

Comment: I don't follow. Please clarify and give an example (text and expected replacement).

Comment: I would like to replace the end of this searched srting "slcassdsap01.*" with \\.*

Comment: So, turn `slcassdsap01FOO` into `slcassdsap01\FOO`?!

Comment: Turn slcsdtp01.* into slcsdtp01\\.*
please remind that i found that by searching /s[w|l].*[0-9].*

Comment: doesn't this work for you? `s/\v(blahblah\d+)(.*)/\1\\\\\2/` better in your question give detailed requirement, what should your text look like, before and after.

Comment: I closed your original attempt because your second answer is better, but still isn't up to standards (as you see by the downvotes). This seems to be a very basic search & replace problem, something that almost any Vim tutorial covers.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your search pattern in escaped parentheses `\(\)`, and use a backreference `\1` in the replacement string:

```
:%s/\(s[w|l].*[0-9]\)\.\*/\1\\\\.*/g
```

You can have several `\(\)` subexpressions in your search string, and can use them both in the search string itself and in the replacement string via `\1`, `\2`, ... . Subexpressions are simply numbered by order of occurence in the search string.