# VIM - Replace based on a search regex

Tags: regex, search, vim, vi

I've got a file with several (1000+) records like :

```
lbc3.*'

ssa2.*'

lie1.*'

sld0.*'

ssdasd.*'
```

I can find them all by :

```
/s[w|l].*[0-9].*$
```

What i want to do is to replace the final part of each pattern found with \.*'

I can't do `:%s//s[w|l].*[0-9].*$/\\\\\.\*'` because it'll replace all the string, and what i need is only replace the end of it from 
    .*'
to
    \.*'

So the file output is llike :

```
lbc3\\.*'

ssa2\\.*'


lie1\\.*'

sld0\\.*'

ssdasd\\.*'
```

Thanks.

Comment: How does `s[w|l]` match `lbc3`? Surely it would only match one line in your example?

Comment: why you want `ssdasd\\.*'` to be changed? What do you mean by `s[w|l]` ?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27525223/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the solution is to use a *capture*.  Put `\(`...`\)` around the part of the regex that matches what you want to keep, and use `\1` to include whatever matched that part of the regex in the replacement string:

```
   s/\(s[w|l].*[0-9].*\)\.\*'$/\1\\.*'/
```

Since you're really just inserting a backslash between two strings that you aren't changing, you could use a second set of parens and `\2` for the second one:

```
   s/\(s[w|l].*[0-9].*\)\(\.\*'\)$/\1\\\2/
```

Alternatively, you could use `\zs` and `\ze` to delimit just the part of the string you want to replace:

```
   s/s[w|l].*p0-9].*\zs\ze\*\'$/\\/
```

Comment: Forget the capture group, use `\zs`!

Comment: Good suggestion, @PeterRincker.  Added it to the answer.